# Angular - Facebook Share Button Only Appears After Refresh

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've just added the Facebook share button to my Angular site however it only appears once I refresh the page.

So i have the Facebook SDK JS loading in my index.html (as taken from their webpage).

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then I have an ng-view (and another .html page where i actually have the Share button):

```
<div class="fb-share-button"
          data-href="http://www.exampleurl.com"
          data-layout="button">
</div>
```

Any ideas why the button only appears after the page refresh. Is it ok to have to Facebook sdk JS in my index and use the share button with ng-view?

Thanks.

Comment: I just try to use `fb-share-button`. It's look ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it to work by calling FB.XFBML.parse() from my controller - like this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app")
      .controller("myController", myController);

    function myController() {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this after init solved this issue.

```
if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined'&& FB != null) { FB.XFBML.parse(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with more simply.
My index.html

reviews.html

```
  <div
class="fb-comments"
[attr.data-href]="url"
data-width="100%"
data-numposts="5"
```

> 

and in reviews.ts file

```
declare var FB: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

}